# Increase # of rows displayed in a drop down list in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

How do I increase, to more than 8, the number of rows displayed in a drop down list in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question can be found at https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/354284-help-increasing-number-rows-displayed-data-validation-list.html.  The answer given there by Sous2817 is:

"The 8 visible rows is a limitation of data validation. You can use a combo box to achieve the results you want. Check here for the "how to": http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html"

The link listed in the answer is still functional.